# How can I make an associative-array lookup case-insensitive?

Tags: bash

I have code like this:

```
declare -A colortable=(
    ["bcbcbc"]="250"
    ["c6c6c6"]="251"
    ["d0d0d0"]="252"
    ["dadada"]="253"
    ["e4e4e4"]="254"
    ["eeeeee"]="255"
)

# get colors from byobu config
if [ -f ~/.config/byobu/color.tmux ]; then
    source ~/.config/byobu/color.tmux
else
    BYOBU_DARK="\#bcbcbc"
fi

# cut the first two characters
BYOBUCOLOR="${BYOBU_DARK:2}";
#echo $BYOBUCOLOR

LOCALCOLOR="${colortable[$BYOBUCOLOR]}";
```

This works fine, *except* when the value in my `color.tmux` is defined with upper-case characters instead of lower-case. How can I make the lookup case-insensitive?

Comment: BTW, note that a backslash is only guaranteed to be stored as a literal inside single quotes; `\#` in double quotes is unspecified, and can have its behavior change between releases.

Comment: ...as another aside, consider `declare -p varname` or `printf '%s=%q\n' varname "$varname"` rather than `echo "$varname"` when you want to unambiguously determine what a variable contains.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/cEsCCh, emitting `250` as output, not an empty string. Can't fix a problem if the code you gave here doesn't actually have it.

Comment: (as another aside -- all-caps variables are used by the shell and POSIX utilities, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to change the shell's behavior; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph; note in reading it that setting a shell variable will automatically overwrite any environment variable that exists with the same name, with no explicit `export` needed).

Comment: ...anyhow, I quite doubt that this is a bash version change that makes the difference -- does one of the two machines have, perhaps, a `~/.config/byobu/color.tmux` file?

Comment: Thank you for all your advises. This is real stupid. My actual problem was, that in `color.tmux` the colors are defined in numbes and capitalized letters, while in the array they are defined as lower case. I had not tested this. Sorry for the noise ****sneaks out****

Comment: full color table credits go [here](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/719710) btw

Comment: Edited into something that's still a question, even in light of the above clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a variable to lowercase during parameter expansion with `${varname,,}`. Thus, change the line doing the lookup to:

```
LOCALCOLOR="${colortable[${BYOBUCOLOR,,}]}"
```

...to always use a lower-case version of `BYOBUCOLOR` to do the lookup.

---

<sub>(By the way, insofar as you can, consider switching to lower-case variable names: All-caps names risk conflicting with names meaningful to the shell and to POSIX-specified tools -- just as how `for PATH in */` breaks the ability to run other commands, but `for path in */` is safe. See fourth paragraph of the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html on this point, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable even if `export` is not explicitly called).</sub>